# How can I attach EntityFramework item from different context?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have  types called **Employee, Upload**, and **UploadType** which have some in-memory computed properties(ie. not database computed properties) that area dependent on a complex navigation property. Therefore, I need to load the related type every time I load the item.

```
public class Employee 
{
    public Upload Photo {get;set;} 
    public Int32 PhotoId {get;set;}
} 
public class Upload 
{ 
   public UploadType UploadType {get;set;}
   public Int32 UploadTypeId {get;set;}
   [NotMapped]
   public String ServerLocation => 
     HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($".../{UploadType.Description}/FileName.pdf");
}
public class UploadType { ... }
```

The problem is that the file is uploaded asyn and later added to the employee that owns it.

```
var uploadType = database.UploadTypes.Single(t => t.Id = utId);
var upload = new Upload() { 
   UploadType = uploadyType;
   UploadTypeId = utId;
}; // Now I can use my in memory computed path.
```

The only problem is that since this is saved out of band during a new employee creation, the context that is used for the upload type is different than that when I actually create the employee and attach the upload.

1. upload doc -> saved in session
2. create employee -> get doc and attach it to employee.

So, when I save the photo the program complains about the different context(of the related upload type of course). 
I can set the UploadType as Detached but then the item is recreated in the UploadType table which is definitely not good.

Is there a way to reload that entity from the correct context before saving so this doesn't happen?

Comment: You need to detach it from the original context and attach it to the new context.

Comment: I can detach State =EntityState.Detached How, can I attach it to the new context?

Comment: `db.Set<T>().Attach(obj);` or `db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`